# Get single value from Pandas DataFrame, and raise Exception if ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key-value

It's a fairly common use case for me, that I want to get a specific value from a pandas dataframe, knowing, that if the data hasn't somehow gotten messed up, there should only be one value fulfilling the particular selection criteria:

What I commonly do is:

```
myvals = df[df['criterion']=='value']['parameterofinterest'].values
if len(myvals) != 1:
    raise ValueError('Something messed up the data integrity.')
myvalue = myvals[0]
```

This is quite a bit of boilerplate code and it seems like something excessively basic to implement as a function *outside* of Pandas. Do you know if there is any Pandas function already, which could help me out here.

Comment: sample data available to reproduce the same error?

Comment: It can be any sort of data where `value` is expected to only be present once on the `criterion` column.

Comment: Could you do a preliminary check on all values? Something like `(df['criterion'].value_counts() == 1).all()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.item()` is the correct way to extract a single value from a 
 conditional selection of a `pd.DataFrame` object - while raising an exception if more than one items are present.

```
import pandas as pd
a = [{'a':3, 'b':4},{'a':2, 'b':4}]
c = pd.DataFrame(a)
c[c['b']==4]['a'].values
c[c['b']==4]['a'].item()
```

The exception raised is currently:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there are possible 3 states - no value - it return `len=0`, match more values - it return `len>1` and for scalar `len==1`.

So your code seems correctly, only a bit was improved:

```
myvals = df.loc[df['criterion']=='value', 'parameterofinterest']

if len(myvals) == 1:
    myvals = myvals.item()        
else:
   raise ValueError('Something messed up the data integrity.')
```

It can be wrapped to function:

```
def scalar_only(mask_col, val, another_col):
    myvals = df.loc[df[mask_col]==val, another_col]

    if len(myvals) != 1:
        raise ValueError('Something messed up the data integrity.')
    else:
        return myvals.item()
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'parameterofinterest': [25.0, 38.0, 34.6], 
                  'criterion': ['value', 'aa', 'bb']})


print (scalar_only('criterion', 'value', 'parameterofinterest'))
25.0
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'parameterofinterest': [25.0, 38.0, 34.6], 
                  'criterion': ['dd', 'aa', 'bb']})


print (scalar_only('criterion', 'value', 'parameterofinterest'))
```

> ValueError: Something messed up the data integrity.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'parameterofinterest': [25.0, 38.0, 34.6], 
                  'criterion': ['value', 'value', 'bb']})


print (scalar_only('criterion', 'value', 'parameterofinterest'))
```

> ValueError: Something messed up the data integrity.

Comment: Thank you. Why exactly is your version improved? (why use `.loc` and why use `.item()` instead of `.values[0]`? And why use if/else when raise would terminate the code anyway?)

Comment: I use `loc` because it is faster and recomended [check 145](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). `.values[0]` is alternative to `item()`.

Comment: Hmmm, so my answer is not helpful?

Comment: it's helpful, in that it shows a slightly variant (and as you say, possibly somewhat faster) way to express my boilerplate code. I was more interested in whether or not pandas is offering a more comprehensive function for this. It seems like a fairly common use case.

Comment: I understand now. I think no. But if no problem if error exception is different (not so clear), working `myvals = df.loc[df['criterion']=='value', 'parameterofinterest'].item()` - it works only if scalar output, else get error `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

Comment: @TheChymera the initial query should be performed with loc so as to reduce the calls to getitem from 2 down to 1. The is what jezrael has shown. Your use case has not been wrapped up into a single api call but there are many ways to do it. That said, this is as concise as you’re going to find. You may have been hoping for a better solution, but there isn’t at the moment. This is your answer.